# Generic class use type as value, or pass property as index for indexed type

Tags: typescript, generics, typescript-generics, mapped-types

I have a class like this

```js
interface Events {
    ready: [Date];
    start: [];
    stop: [];
}

export abstract class Event<Name extends keyof Events> {
    public abstract readonly name: Name;

    public someFunction(args: Events[Name]) {
        callSomeFunction(this.name, args);
    }
}
```

And I'm asking if some way I could remove either the generic type or the `name` property to avoid repetition in my code ?

Comment: Can you point out the repetition explicitly or what the problem is?  I mean, I understand that `name` and `Name` appear multiple times in your code, but each of those uses have different meanings so it's hard for me to imagine anything more succinct.  It's like asking if I can remove one of the instances of `x` in the arrow function `x => x + 2`.

Comment: I mean, they both have the same type, and if we create a class that extends, we will do `class extends Event<'ready'>` for exemple, but we will also have to set `name` value to `'ready'`, can't I just convert `Name` to a value as it will always be a string ?

Comment: So `class ReadyEvent extends Event<"ready"> { readonly name = "ready"; }` is too much repetition for you?  You could refactor to something like `class ReadyEvent extends SubEvent("ready") { }` for an appropriate definition of `SubEvent`, like [this](https://tsplay.dev/N9AzjN), but that may or may not be worth it for your use case.  Is that what you're looking for?  If not, could you elaborate?

Comment: Oh that's clever, thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay I found something that works :

```js
export abstract class Event {
    public abstract readonly name: keyof Events;

    public someFunction(args: Events[this['name']]) {
        callSomeFunction(this.name, args);
    }
}
```

So I can do this :

```js
class ReadyEvent extends Event {
    name = 'ready';
}
```

Without putting multiple times `'ready'` ^^

Comment: Oh, sure... polymorphic `this` is one way to go.  You might want to show how the subclassing works here (e.g., `class ReadyEvent extends Event { readonly name = "ready" }`).